# Resolve module in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, path, tsc

I have kind of a problem. I have some typescript features and I try to compile then in js.

this is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

In the end I run `tsc` and that work well, my js files are created.
But when I run `node myfile.js` I get an error:

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/salsa/test/analyst/amlf-analyst/src/pipes/thunes/p01'`

and yes I know the .js is missing at the end of the path. But in my ts files I get an error If I specify the extension. So who can tsc compile the path with the js exension at the end.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How are you importing the `src/pipes/thunes/p01` file?

Comment: in typescript: ```import pipeAgg from '../../pipes/thunes/p01'```

Comment: _"But in my ts files I get an error If I specify the extension."_ That's the actual problem. You have to specify the extension. What is the error message and where does it come from when you specify the file extension?

Comment: @jabaa so if I add the .ts extension in one of my imports I get this error:
```An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension```

Comment: You have to add a `.js` extension. It's `import pipeAgg from '../../pipes/thunes/p01.js'`

Comment: @jabaa but I don't have js files before compiling so, It will be wrong.
and the fact of compiling mean I shouldn't have to update the compilated codebase

Comment: TypeScript handles this for you. The `.js` files don't have to exist. TypeScript internally replaces the `.js` extensions with `.ts` extensions.

Comment: An example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-cfcumg?file=package.json